# Bitwise operation in ActionScript 3 compare to Java

Tags: java, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am researching this AS3 code that write a `BitString` into a `ByteArray`. Source: [JPGEncoder#writeBits()](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/images/JPGEncoder.as#L239)

```
private var byteout:ByteArray;
private var bytenew:int = 0;
private var bytepos:int = 7;

private function writeBits(bs:BitString):void
{
    var value:int = bs.val;
    var posval:int = bs.len-1;
    while (posval >= 0) {
        if (value & uint(1 << posval)) {
            bytenew |= uint(1 << bytepos);
        }
        posval--;
        bytepos--;
        if (bytepos < 0) {
            if (bytenew == 0xFF) {
                writeByte(0xFF);
                writeByte(0);
            } else {
                writeByte(bytenew);
            }
            bytepos=7;
            bytenew=0;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't understand part of the code.

- What is `uint(1 << bytepos)`?
- What is the if condition `if (value & uint(1 << posval))`?

  - I don't know whether the `&` is "and" bit operator, or "and" condition.
  - Does `if(number)` in AS3 means `if(number != 0)` ?

What is these AS3 code equivalent in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitwise operations in Java are somewhat awkward, because Java has no unsigned types.
So when you intend to work with bytes, you should make sure you stay with bytes. Things like 0x0f | 0x80 -> 0b1000 1111 done with bytes must be cast to bytes all the time:

```
System.out.printf("%x - %x - (byte)%x - (int)%x\n", 
                   (byte)0x80, 
                   (byte)0xf, 
                   (byte)((byte)0x80|(byte)0xf), 
                    (int)((byte)0x80|(byte)0xf));

OUTPUT:
80 - f - (byte)8f - (int)ffffff8f
```

Having said this, you may want to work with ints from the beginning and cast to bytes later.

The code you present transcribes the BitString into a bit stream cut into bytes.

A special case is handled if all bits of a byte are set, in that case 0xff00 is output.

> What is uint(1 << bytepos)?

This moves the lhs of the operator by `bytepos` bits to the left:

```
1 << 4 -> 0b00010000
```

> What is the if condition if (value & uint(1 << posval))? 
>   I don't know whether the & is "and" bit operator, or "and" condition.

`&` is bitwise AND, `&&` is boolean.

The operation is `!= 0` -> `TRUE` if the bit at `posval` position is set. This is the condition to set the corresponding bit in the byte.

Transferring the code to Java should be straightforward actually. I would suggest you use plain `int` in java and convert to byte just before you write:

```
byte realByte = (byte)(intbyte & (byte)0xff);
writeByte(realByte);
```

This way, you avoid constant casting to byte and you avoid the above mentioned problem with negative bytes.

Comment: Java don't have unsigedint, so do I need to apply type cast `uint()`? Or just doing everything in normal int, then write byte using `(byte)(intbyte & (byte)0xff)`?

Comment: the code uses the lower 8 bits only, just ignore the uint stuff and just use java `int` and as said use writeByte() with the explicitely converted byte.

Comment: So the if condition in Java is `if ((value & (1 << posval)) != 0)` ?

Comment: Yes, that will do it.

Comment: uint() is prevents runtime error in AS3. You can see the example in: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_left_shift

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are the **bit shift operators** of AS3. You will find that Java uses the same syntax.

This [link](http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/2010/08/bitwise-operations-in-actionscript-3/) about bit operations in AS3. The Java documentation page [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) explains what the operators do.

As for the if condition, it checks if the 'posval'-th bit from the right in *value* is 1. It "selects" the bit by applying the **bitwise and** between *value* and the shifting of value 1 ( 000...01 in binary) by *posval* bits.